# I want to iterate through my priority queue in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am implementing a generic priority queue in C# i used SortedDictionary for the priority keys and Queue for the values.
Now i want to iterate through it with a **foreach loop** with a condition to skip over queue items with priority 0.

This is my priority queue class

```
      public class PQ<Tpriority, Titem>
{
    readonly SortedDictionary<Tpriority, Queue<Titem>> value;
    public PQ(IComparer<Tpriority> priorityComparer)
    {

        value = new SortedDictionary<Tpriority, Queue<Titem>>(priorityComparer);


    }
    public PQ() : this(Comparer<Tpriority>.Default) { }

    public bool Check{ get { return value.Any(); }}

    public int Count
    {
        get { return value.Sum(q => q.Value.Count); }
    }

    public void Add(Tpriority priority, Titem item)
    {
        if (!value.ContainsKey(priority))
        {
            AddQueueOfPriority(priority);
        }
        value[priority].Enqueue(item);
    }


    private void AddQueueOfPriority(Tpriority priority)
    {
        value.Add(priority, new Queue<Titem>());
    }

    public Titem Next()
    {
        if (value.Any())
            return Next_FHP();
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The queue is empty");
    }

    private Titem Next_FHP()
    {
        KeyValuePair<Tpriority, Queue<Titem>> first = value.First();
        Titem nextItem = first.Value.Dequeue();
        if (!first.Value.Any())
        {
            value.Remove(first.Key);
        }
        return nextItem;
    }

    public SortedDictionary<Tpriority, Queue<Titem>>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return value.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public interface IEnumerator<Tpriority, Titem>{}
```

And this is my main program
I was able to get all my needed actions to work fine just this

```
    static
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var first = new PQ<int, string>();
        first.Add(1, "random1");
        first.Add(0, "random2");
        first.Add(2, "random3");

        while (first.Check)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first.Next());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(first.Check);


        /*it gives the error "Can not convert
        type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,System.Collections.Generic.Queue<string>>'
        to exam.PQ<int, string>"*/

        foreach (PQ<int, string> h in first)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: The error is clear. Each dictionary item is a `KeyValuePair`, so you cannot iterate the dictionary items (unless complicating the logic) to do something about each Queue. What have you tried to solve the issue?

Comment: I was thinking of using the IEnumerator but now i know i can't iterate through, i'm not really sure it would work so i might try another approach in implementing the priority queue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to add your own method on your PQ class, that returns a collection of Queue items that pass your (any) validation check.

So something like this on your PQ class

```
 public IEnumerable<Queue<Titem>> GetItems(Tpriority priority)
 {
     var validKeys = value.Keys.Where(x => !x.Equals(priority) );
     return value.Where(x => validKeys.Contains(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value);
 }
```

Then you can iterate over it like this

```
foreach (var h in first.GetItems(0))
{

}
```

You might want a better name for the method though, which clearly states what it's going to do.

Update...

To just print out the values, you could do something like this.

```
public IEnumerable<Titem> GetItems(Tpriority priority)
{
    var validKeys = value.Keys.Where(x => !x.Equals(priority) );
    return value
        .Where(x => validKeys.Contains(x.Key))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Value);
}
```

And here it is broken up into bits with a few comments

```
public IEnumerable<Titem> GetItems(Tpriority priority)
    {
        // Find all the keys in the dictionary which do not match the supplied value
        var validKeys = value.Keys.Where(x => !x.Equals(priority) );

        // Find all the values in the dictionary where the key is in the valid keys list
        var validItems = value
            .Where(x => validKeys.Contains(x.Key));

        // Because an individual queue item is actually a collection of items,
        // SelectMany flattens them all into one collection
        var result = validItems.SelectMany(x => x.Value);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you the method and iteration works but it prints out this System.Collections.Generic.Queue1[System.String] System.Collections.Generic.Queue1[System.String.

instead of the values.

Comment: A queue is a collection of items. I'll update my answer to just give you values, if that's all you want

Comment: Yes please and Thank you.

Comment: If you found it helpful, please feel free to upvote the answer

Comment: Thank you very much work perfectly, now i just need to understand it.

Comment: I've updated it and added a few comments to explain the bits